# ASPNET Core + Entity Framework 6 + ASPNET Identity 2 on Azure Service Fabric

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-service-fabric

We're trying to bring an ASPNET MVC 5 solution to ASPNET Core cause we have directions to move to Azure Service Fabric for production.

Given that a way to get an MVC web site running into Service Fabric, is to use a Self Hosting tech like ASPNET Core (running on top of full .NET Framework), from our existing codebase we'd like to change just the MVC pieces of our solution, leaving the rest as is wherever possible.

These two pieces must remain untouched because of reducing change workload, but most, for customizations on top (mostly for Identity)

- Entity Framework 6 (tested and good to go)
- ASPNET Identity 2 ([Multitenancy](https://github.com/JSkimming/AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Multitenant) & Custom Password hashing must be left unchanged -this project has been ported since ASPNET Membership days, and its actively running in prod since then-)

**The issue: ASPNET Identity 2 and its compatibility into the ASPNET Core stack.**

Being an OWIN stack player, we're finding hard to make use of it into ASPNET Core's `Configure()` (for piping) and `ConfigureServices()` (for DI)

Anyone out there going thru something alike?

Comment: See this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity

Comment: Thanks for stepping in @SteveGreene! We're trying not to migrate to EF Core nor ASPNET Identity Core, which is what the referred document is about I think.

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet core does not use `Entity Framework 6` It Uses `Entity Framework Core` and `asp identity core` these two are much alike but they are slightly different from `asp net MVC`.
all configurations are done in `Startup.cs` in core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Please use this as reference for migrating your code.